# How to check if path is file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, fs

Is there any clean way to check if a path is a file or directory?

Currently I am using this:

```
exports.isDirectory = (dirPath) => {
  return fs.lstatSync(dirPath).isDirectory()
}
```

But my problem here is that if `dirPath` does not exist yet, then `lstatSync` gives out an error.

Then I also tried:

```
exports.getFileName = (filePath) => {
  return filePath.split(/[\\\/]/).pop()
}

exports.isDirectory = (dirPath) => {
  return exports.getFileName(dirPath) === ''
}
```

And call:

```
const home = require('os').homedir()
const sampleLoc = path.join(home, '/.folder/another'))
isDirectory(sampleLoc)
```

But it only basically thinks `another` is the filename and returns `false` on `isDirectory`.

Can't really check for the presence of `.` (like an extension of a file name) since my folders can have dots anywhere on its name.

How can I check if the given path is for a file or directory? (considering it does not exist yet at the point of checking)?

Help!

Comment: How would you know if something was a file or directory if it didn't exist yet? Filesystems generally have the same rules for naming files and directories. Do they follow specific patterns in your case?

Comment: Because for this module I am working on, it will be handling the creation of folders/files (recursively). Input can either be a directory path or a specific file. So I need to make sure what the path is before I start creating them.

Comment: Do all of the files that have to be generated have an extension?

Comment: Hi @eol - yes they do! Thanks